# Combine multiple ssis packages into one package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have multiple `SSIS` packages that I have created. All of them are from the same server but different dbs are used (3 dbs used). The destination is to a different server but same db. Each package goes to a different destination table though  each query is different with different columns.

Is there a way to combine all of these `SSIS` packages into one package?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the use of this? For maintenance perspective, keep them in separate package. Create a `master package` which uses Execute Package Task` to call out these packages and run them parallel if possible.

Comment: each package is used for reporting purposes. I use powerBI to call each table and make graphs and what not. I use the packages to update the tables so the most up to date data is available. How would i use execute package task? Sorry I haven't used it before so im not sure how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways, but without knowing what the problem is that you're trying to solve, there's no way to suggest one that will be worth doing.

Comment: As Prebhat says, just create a 'Control' package that has an `Execute Package` task for each package you want to run in one go.